# Jupyter Notebook won't recognize a newly created environment variable

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, jupyter-notebook

I created an environment variable to store an API key.  I can access it just fine via python

```
import os
os.environ['MY_VAR']
```

But the same command in a Jupyter Notebook raises the error

```
except KeyError:
    668             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 669             raise KeyError(key) from None
    670         return self.decodevalue(value)
```

I can call previously made variables in Jupyter just fine, but the one I made *today* is uncallable.

I'm not in a virtual environment for either.

Comment: Are you setting (and exporting) the env var in the shell from which you launch jupyter-notebook?

Comment: No I was not.  That was my problem.  Side note: how are they "environmental" variables if I can't call them in a different shell?  I thought the whole point is that these are universally accessible.

Comment: They are 'environment', not 'environmental' and the environment in question is a process. No, they are not universally accessible, they are, though, typically passed to subshells or subprocesses. Or defined in config files which shells read. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Design